# CSS and DIV with header and body with scrollable content, and fixed sidebar to right

Tags: html, css

I've been looking around all over, but I can't solve this, so I'm turning here.

I want to make a layout that looks like this:
[image]

The layout consists of three fields:

1. A header at the top with a fixed height, dynamic width, and vertically scrollable content.
2. Body below header, with dynamic width and height, with vertically scrollable content.
3. A sidebar to the right, with a fixed width, dynamic height, and no scroll. (This should remain fixed when you scroll the body content)

Dynamic height and/or width means it will resize with the window, not that it resizes with content.

If anything is unclear or there's any questions, I'll do my best to answer.

edit: one of my (very failed) attempts here: http://jsfiddle.net/uYTht/34/

html structure:

```
<body>
    <div id="header">
        header content
    </div>
    <div id="content">
        body content
    </div>
    <div id="sidebar">
        sidebar content
    </div>
</body>
```

css code:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin-right: 150px;
    background-color: green;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#content {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
#sidebar {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-left: -150px;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    background-color: red;  
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

edit: David below helped me find the way. Basically what I had to use to make it work as I wanted was the calc()-function.

edit edit: Jack below came up with a solution that didn't use calc(), which I must say I prefer. Thank you all very much for the help!

Comment: You... want someone to create this for you?

Comment: of course; adding it here and editing the question. This is (one of my) very failed attempts. http://jsfiddle.net/uYTht/31/

Comment: Sorry, did a margin-left instead of a margin-right.
http://jsfiddle.net/uYTht/34/ should be more correct. (although still not working)
Updated question as well.

Comment: You have to define the height. At least in JSFiddle, `height:100%` for the parent does literally nothing. It is based on a parent element. Check my answer for more details and a working prototype of your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a simple fiddle, that doesn't use `calc` (support isn't great - http://caniuse.com/calc, and then there's the big unknown of any performance penalty you may/may not hit using it..)

It's very straight forward, using simple CSS.

http://jsfiddle.net/ruYGH/3/

Comment: That's real nice! I had to add overflow: hidden on the sidebar as well, otherwise if you moused over that you could scroll down with the scroll wheel and see a white footer for as long as the content of the sidebar would go. Thank you very much!

Comment: You're absolutely right regarding the sidebar! Sorry about that! I was cleaning up the CSS prior to linking to the fiddle, and accidentally removed the property. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using defined heights and widths for each of the elements with the `overflow` property.

To make a box scrollable (if the content doesn't fit inside):

```
overflow:auto;
```

To make a box not scrollable:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

**Note that if the height and width are undefined, the element will grow to fit all of the contents.**

I made a (not very pretty, but functional) example here:

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3TCX/3/)

### Edit:

You can make the sidebar a fixed width and adjust the other elements accordingly with `calc`:

```
.sidebar{
    width: 200px;
}

.left{
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}
```

The [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n3TCX/3/) has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: That looks really good, gonna see if I can make the whole thing fit the browser window height-wise as well. Gonna come back shortly. :)

Comment: Ah, one issue that I can't seem to get by: I'd like to have the sidebar at a fixed width (not a percentage), which messes with the width of the header...

Comment: Ah very nice! Now if I only could get the height of the whole kit match the browser windows height... still looking into it, I'll be back again soon. Thank you very much!

edit: nevermind, that was very easy, probably shouldn't be doing this at 3am. :) Thank you again for the answer, seems to be working exactly as I wanted now.

Answer (score 0):

Style the divs with "overflow" to put the scroll bars where you want them and prevent them where you don't want them.  You will also use overflow to specify what you want to happen to your content if it should happen to be too big to fit in your fixed width areas.

[Chris Coyer is always a knowledgeable CSS resource](http://css-tricks.com/the-css-overflow-property/)

As far as the layout goes, it is a walk in the park if you use a two column table with rowspan="2" on the second column of the first row and only  one column in the second row.

If you don't want to use tables (there is no good reason not to, but there are thousands of people that will look down on you if you do) then look at using divs with style="display: table...."

Once again [Chris Coyer has an explanation](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Thanks for the fiddle, your overflow css is working it is just that your header and content divs are 100% wide (full screen) and the scroll bars are conceptually under the sidebar. I need to sell you on using that table layout so that you can "dynamically" fix your dimensions so that the browser can know when to scroll instead of expanding the content down indefinitely to fit the size of the content instead of overflowing with the scroll bar.

Comment: Yeah I've been trying that, sorry for not including it earlier.
I just can't get it to work with the page size height-wise, or the divs refuse to align properly... I'm certainly gonna read that page though, thanks! Also added some more relevant things to the question.

Comment: I was actually looking into using a table, but it seemed to make it load a whole lot slower (contains ~650 small images), and also seemed to mess with the lazy loading on the images. Sadly I broke the page with my experimentation, gonna see if I can make it work enough to post a link here soon.
If I can't get this to work now, I'll for sure check out tables again. Thank you!

Comment: You are really there. It wont take much to make your fiddle work.