# Fixed header - scroll to DIV

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

Header on my site has height of 100px and is fixed to top.All content scrolls under it.

Content div bellow it has maring-top of 100px so it is displayed properly under it.
In there, on the left side i have UL list with few links that go to different DIVs inside that page.

When i click on one of them, instead of keeping the 100px margin from top, it dissapears under the fixed header.

I tried to paste the code, but there is simply too much of it, so if anybody can give me a hand and take a look at :http://webnroll.info/test/about-us.html
Try clicking on any link in the left menu and you will see the problem.

Moderators, if i am breaking any rules, i apologize.

Comment: Show atleast the particular functions that gets called on those li clicks

Comment: I believe you can find some answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1854218/anchor-linking-to-a-certain-position-of-the-page

Comment: possible duplicate of [offsetting an html anchor to adjust for fixed header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10732690/offsetting-an-html-anchor-to-adjust-for-fixed-header)

Comment: Similar issue is addressed already on stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21896151/css-and-div-with-header-and-body-with-scrollable-content-and-fixed-sidebar-to-r

Comment: Just checking out the previous posts, and i cant seem to make it work in my case.Will try this one now